# Turning a field value into a column header - MSAccess

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a database where one of the tables has the fields:

`|Tag|Parameter|Value|`

Where each tag can have several parameters but each parameter only has one value.

eg:

```
|Tag|Parameter|Value|
|t10|HHAPRI   |154  |
|t10|LLAPRI   |4    |
|t16|HHAPRI   |12   |
```

How would I got about transforming this, ideally with a query, to something like:

```
|Tag|HHAPRI|LLAPRI|
|T10|154   |4     |
|T16|12    |      |
```

Where each tag appears only once, with all parameters as column headers and the values entered into the fields.

This is the SQL query that generates the table in the first place `Op Parameter` can be treated in the same was as `Parameter` for this purpose.

```
    SELECT tblAlarmPriorities.*, tblOperatingMode.Parameter AS [Op Parameter], tblOperatingMode.Value AS [Op Value], tblOperatingMode.Correct_Operating_Mode, tblOperatingMode.Alarm_Low_Low, tblOperatingMode.Alarm_Low, tblOperatingMode.Alarm_High_High, tblOperatingMode.Alarm_High, tblLookUp.ParameterDesc AS AlarmParamDesc, tblLookUp_1.ParameterDesc AS OpParamDesc, *
FROM ((tblAlarmPriorities LEFT JOIN tblLookUp ON tblAlarmPriorities.Parameter = tblLookUp.ParameterIdent) INNER JOIN tblOperatingMode ON tblAlarmPriorities.CS_Tag = tblOperatingMode.CS_Tag) LEFT JOIN tblLookUp AS tblLookUp_1 ON tblOperatingMode.PARAMETER = tblLookUp_1.ParameterIdent;
```

Comment: Can you provide your SQL Query?

Comment: As in the query which generates the table in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cross-tab query will give the results you're after:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(sValue) AS SumOfsValue
SELECT Tag
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Tag
PIVOT Parameter
```

where `Table1` is the name of your original query.

Comment: Cheers, that's pretty much what I need

Answer (score 2):

This is a crosstab (TRANSFORM) query.

I suggest to use the "new query" wizard for crosstab queries.

- `Tag` is the row header.
- `Parameter` is the column header.
- `Value` is the value :), using an appropriate aggregating function (Sum or First e.g.)

Comment: Can this be used as the datasource for a report?

Comment: That's not so easy, because the number of columns is variable. If it isn't (the set of different parameters is fix), then yes. The output is a datasheet just like from a normal SELECT query.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks! It's got me going in the right direction at least